# How can I set custom length for integer field by using Blueprint class in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> I am trying to set custom length for integer type field from user
>   input.
>   By using Blueprint class I can set custom length for varchar field
>   like ***$table->string('varchar_field',50);***. But I didn't find any way
>   to set custom length for integer field, It takes default length always.

**Ex :**

```
Varchar : 
$table->string('varchar_field',50);

Integer :
$table->integer('interger_field');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that, but you can choose [one of available integer types](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns):

```
// BIGINT equivalent, integers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
$table->bigInteger('interger_field');

// INTEGER equivalent, integers from -2147483648 to 2147483647
$table->integer('interger_field');

// MEDIUMINT equivalent, integers from -8388608 to 8388607
$table->mediumInteger('interger_field');

// SMALLINT equivalent, integers from -32768 to 32767
$table->smallInteger('interger_field');

// TINYINT equivalent, integers from -128 to 127
$table->tinyInteger('interger_field');
```

You will find the description of all integer types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: It set a specific length according to individual  default value. I need to set custom length from user given input. Do you have any other solution to purpose this serve?

Answer (score 5):

Also you can create column with specific length (not tested, but should work):

```
$table->addColumn('integer', 'column_name', ['length' => 50]);
```